# Why is my ubuntu display manager doing this?

Tags: 18.04, gdm, display-manager, kdm

[image]

I rebooted my ubuntu machine and this happened with my display manager - the options on the sidebar jumbled together. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you ever made any alterations to the theme, font, or icons?  Are you using [GNOME](https://stopthemingmy.app)?

Comment: @Nmath not that I know of.. I had a separate issue before that in the process of resolving, I switched out lightdm for gdm3 but now I reversed it and got this